# How can I get a "clean" list all currently banned IPs on fail2ban? One line per IP

Tags: fail2ban

How can I cleanly list all currently banned IPs on fail2ban? with one IP per line?

Below is the list I get when I execute :

```
fail2ban-client status sshd
```

on my Ubunutu 18.04 server. I know the bare minimum when it comes to linux and servers. I don't even know how to get the version of fail2ban I am using, and yes, I googled it a lot.

Is there a way to get one IP per line?

> fail2ban-client status sshd Status for the jail: sshd
>  |- Filter
>  |  |-
> Currently failed: 3 
> |  |- Total failed:   1266 
> |  `- File list: /var/log/auth.log <br>`- Actions
>     |- Currently banned:    118 
>    |-
> Total banned: 345  
>   `- Banned IP list:   
> 61.177.173.10 49.234.214.215
> 152.231.140.150 180.76.247.65 43.129.26.69 196.206.231.249 43.153.27.174 43.157.1.29 180.167.207.234 43.252.62.60 43.154.88.243 200.7.168.217 64.227.187.235 186.226.37.45 183.98.146.157 182.93.7.194 143.244.163.108 122.194.229.62 112.85.42.74 61.177.173.36 177.91.52.133 103.124.94.169 122.194.229.54 61.177.172.59 61.177.173.16 61.177.173.40 141.98.11.23 61.177.172.108 61.177.173.37 112.85.42.53 122.194.229.40 189.202.214.250 112.85.42.87 49.248.153.6 143.110.243.129 43.129.24.85 112.85.42.151 134.19.146.45 61.177.172.76 112.85.42.229 61.177.172.89 61.177.172.91 61.177.172.61 195.29.51.135 45.67.34.253 20.205.39.78 194.165.16.5 61.177.172.124 160.16.209.119 61.177.173.35 177.19.138.138 103.63.108.25 61.177.172.60 43.154.205.162 138.219.192.207 222.82.211.78 61.177.172.160 112.85.42.15 165.232.189.7 61.177.173.39 147.182.179.237 207.154.211.157 120.92.11.9 209.97.162.0 45.234.188.11 167.71.220.220 104.248.140.201 90.189.182.30 68.183.236.92 103.86.49.28 61.177.172.98 43.154.137.134 207.154.228.201 61.177.173.42 43.154.2.84 45.135.232.155 139.59.64.41 43.154.58.123 218.92.0.221 88.215.177.224 193.169.255.38 51.140.185.84 46.101.137.28 122.194.229.92 139.59.187.229 5.180.31.119 112.85.42.73 185.59.139.99 122.194.229.65 1.15.251.60 46.19.139.42 165.22.198.10 61.177.173.44 193.168.195.23 61.177.172.174 89.232.192.40 61.177.173.41 82.196.4.168 61.177.172.87 64.227.108.47 159.89.55.150 117.122.212.78 159.223.148.195 206.217.131.233 138.197.222.211 121.225.234.182 164.92.106.112 185.220.102.251 36.110.228.254 45.153.160.132 171.25.193.20 113.31.117.79 51.143.96.123 159.89.29.240 172.247.15.76 159.223.229.50 14.161.50.104 68.183.125.190

p.s. I don't really mind listing the IPs here. My server is not a public server, so anyone being banned is 99% a bot, or something else up to no good.

Answer (score 2):

Copy and paste it to the terminal
It will cleanly list all currently banned IPs on fail2ban in a table with little more info.

```
while true; do
  # Clear the terminal
  clear

  # Display static header
  echo -e "\e[1;44m        List of Banned IPs         \n\e[0m"

  # Fetch dynamic info
  IPs=$(sudo fail2ban-client status sshd | grep "Banned IP list:" | sed 's/.*Banned IP list://g' | tr -s ' ' '\n')
  current_count=$(echo -e "$IPs" | wc -l)
  total_count=$(grep "Ban " /var/log/fail2ban.log | wc -l)

  # Display Currently Banned IPs and Total Banned to Date
  echo -e "\e[1;32m   Currently Banned IPs: $current_count\e[0m"
  echo -e "\e[1;32m   Total Banned to Date: $total_count\n\e[0m"
  

  # Display table headers
  echo -e " ┌─────┬──────────────────────┬───────────┐"
  echo -e " │ No. │          IP          │  Unban In │"
  echo -e " ├─────┼──────────────────────┼───────────┤"

  # Parse each IP and look up its ban time in the log file
  echo -e "$IPs" | awk '{print NR, $1}' | while read -r num ip; do
    ban_time=$(grep "$ip" /var/log/fail2ban.log | tail -1 | awk '{print $1 " " $2}' | xargs -I {} date -d {} +%s)
    current_time=$(date +%s)
    time_left=$(( 3600 - (current_time - ban_time) ))
    mins=$(( (time_left + 59) / 60 ))
    [ $mins -eq 0 ] && mins=1
    printf " │ %2d  │     %-15s  │%4d mins  │\n" "$num" "$ip" "$mins"
    
  done
echo " └─────┴──────────────────────┴───────────┘"  # Line below each IP
  counter=0
  server_info=""

  for i in {59..0}; do
    if ((counter % 10 == 0)); then
      cpu_temp=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp 2>/dev/null)
      cpu_load=$(uptime | awk -F 'load average: ' '{print $2}')
      disk_usage=$(df -h / | awk 'NR==2 {print $5}')
      memory_usage=$(free -m | awk 'NR==2 {print $3 "/" $2 "MB"}')
      logged_users=$(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u | wc -l)
      logged_users_list=$(who | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ', ' | sed 's/,$//')
      cpu_temp_c=$(awk -v temp="$cpu_temp" 'BEGIN{printf "%.1f", temp / 1000}')


      server_info="\e[1;32m\n - Server Info:\n - CPU Load : $cpu_load\n - CPU Temp : $cpu_temp_c °C\n - Disk Usage : $disk_usage\n - Memory Usage : $memory_usage\n - Count of unique logged-in users : $logged_users\n - Logged in as : $logged_users_list\n\e[0m"
    fi

    echo -e "\e[1;32m  Current Time: $(date '+%H:%M:%S')\e[0m"
    echo " ──────────────────────────────────────────"
    echo -e "$server_info"
    echo " ──────────────────────────────────────────"
    counter=$((counter + 1))
    sleep 1

    # Clear the lines for server info and time, but no more than that
    echo -ne "\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K\033[A"
  done
done
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Very nice.  I did have to modify this by adding `sudo` before `grep "$ip" /var/log/fail2ban.log`, since it was not readable by all users by default.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex:
`fail2ban-client status sshd  | grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `banip` property, which gives a list of IPs.

`fail2ban-client get jail-name banip`

Output:

```
1.2.3.4 111.222.333.444
```

You can also specify a separator:

`fail2ban-client get jail-name banip "|"`

Output:

```
1.2.3.4|111.222.333.444
```

To get one IP per line (I didn't see a way to use "newline" as a separator, so I use `tr`):

`fail2ban-client get jail-name banip | tr ' ' '\n'`

Output:

```
1.2.3.4
111.222.333.444
```